# Присвоение значения переменной в c++ переданной по указателю

Tags: c++, указатели

```
string m = "dds";
string* temp = new string;
```

Как с помощью конструктора копирования из `string` присвоить значению, на которое ссылается `temp`, значение `m`?

p.s. Правильно ли я понимаю, что при разыменовании `temp` возвращется rvalue? изменение которого никак не влияет на содержимое переменной, на которую указывает `temp`?

Comment: Результат разыменования (встроенный унарный оператор `*`) - всегда lvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вас интересует именно *конструктор копирования*, то должен вас огорчить - присваивать (а не создавать) с помощью конструктора - нонсенс.

Думаю, вы просто хотите

```
string * temp = new string(m);
```

Здесь конструктор копирования используется при создании объекта, на который указывает `temp`.

Если присвоить - то с помощью *копирующего присваивания*:

```
*temp = m;
```

Нет, неправильно. `*temp` вполне lvalue. Смотрите сами - https://ideone.com/ZkagqR